# org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, osgi, apache-karaf, osgi-bundle

I am developing a **OSGI** based **Spring MVC** application, I am using **Karaf** for deploying the bundles. My spring MVC application is a war file. I placed my bundle file in the deploy directory

karaf@root()> web:list

### ID  | State       | Web-State   | Level | Web-ContextPath         | Name

125 | Active      | Deployed    | 80    | /sample                 | tomcat-sample (0)
168 | Active      | Deployed    | 80    | /spring-kalees-mvc-host | spring-kalees-mvc-host (0.0.1.SNAPSHOT)

I am having a **servlet(To verify teh bundle)** and Others are Spring

Url: http://*a****t:8181/spring-kalees-mvc-host/hello (Servlet mapping) **works fine**
But, 
Url : http://*a*****t:8181/spring-kalees-mvc-host/osgi/osgi.htm (Spring based controller ) **is not working**

It is throwing error like,

**HTTP ERROR 503**

Problem accessing /spring-kalees-mvc-host/osgi/saySomething. Reason:

```
    org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:
PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Class' for property 'contextClass'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find class [org.springframework.osgi.web.context.support.OsgiBundleXmlWebApplicationContext]
Caused by:

org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder$1: org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:
PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Class' for property 'contextClass'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find class [org.springframework.osgi.web.context.support.OsgiBundleXmlWebApplicationContext]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.makeUnavailable(ServletHolder.java:483)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:537)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.getServlet(ServletHolder.java:402)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:642)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1448)
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.internal.WelcomeFilesFilter.doFilter(WelcomeFilesFilter.java:192)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1419)

In karaf log file, There was a error entry like below :

org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war - 3.0.0.M3 | Registration exception. Skipping.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener not found by org.danielsoft.learn.spring-kalees-mvc-host [167]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1460)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.0.3.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$400(BundleWiringImpl.java:72)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.0.3.jar:]
    at
```

**I specified the classpath like**

```
<classpath>WEB-INF/lib,WEB-INF/lib/org.springframework.context-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar,WEB-INF/lib/org.springframework.context.support-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar,WEB-INF/classes/,.</classpath>
```

And packed war file with lib files(WEB-INF/lib)

My bundle information is

[image]

Any Idea on this error ?

Comment: Judging from the stacktrace you are trying to build an application with the old Spring-DM packages/bundles. You need to deploy those as well and make sure that your application is importing those.

Comment: @M. Deinum I placed spring dependencies which are used in project  inside karaf's deploy directory.

Comment: The fact that they are deployed doesn't mean they are used. If you don't tell the OSGi war that it shoudl pull in those dependencies they are not visible. Please add your web.xml and MANIFEST.MF ..

Comment: My Files

web.xml -> http://pastebin.com/JYKVAWVF
MANIFEST.MF -> http://pastebin.com/4Qb9h3nu
pom.xml -> http://pastebin.com/2hDvv0PH
spring-kalees-mvc-host-servlet.xml -> http://pastebin.com/AGth5QMb

Comment: As mentioned you are not importing the packages/bundles you need and as such those packages will not be available. Import the OSGi related bundles.

Comment: I have already specified the jars in bundle classpath , 
Bundle-Classpath: WEB-INF/lib,WEB-INF/lib/org.springframework.context-
 3.2.2.RELEASE.jar,WEB-INF/lib/org.springframework.context.support-3.2
 .2.RELEASE.jar,WEB-INF/classes/,.

 If I am wrong, Where to add bundles and What are all the bundles that I have to add ?

Comment: You don't have the OSGi bundles. You only have the core spring framework bundles, not the Spring DM bundles (for which you really should be using Eclipse Gemini now).

Comment: The missing package is `org.springframework.osgi.web.context.support`. You don't seem to either import that or have it on your Bundle-Classpath.

Comment: @M. Deinum I am using karaf, So I have to install spring-dm feature in karaf ?

karaf@root()> feature:install
spring-aspects                  spring-dm-web
spring-instrument               spring-jdbc                     spring-jms                      spring-orm
spring-oxm                      spring-struts                   spring-test                     spring-tx
spring-web                      spring-web-portlet              transaction                     wrapper

Comment: @Neil Bartlett , have it on your Bundle-Classpath ? , How can i add a bundle on the classpath, I just placed in the deploy directory of Karaf.

Comment: I suggest you take a look at [this](http://davidvaleri.wordpress.com/2011/08/17/deploying-spring-mvc-based-web-applications-to-osgi-using-apache-servicemix/) tutorial.

Comment: I referred that site as well, They are using Apache ServiceMix, I am using Apache karaf. I followed that example and developed this application. I am sure I am missing something, If you guide me where I have to look, It will be helpful.

Comment: If you put bundle in the deploy directory then you will need to import the package in your own bundle.

Comment: @NeilBartlett That Application(http://davidvaleri.wordpress.com/2011/08/17/deploying-spring-mvc-based-web-applications-to-osgi-using-apache-servicemix/) works fine. I am having a query,

Step 2 : features:addurl mvn:valeri.blog.examples/spring-mvc-smx/1.1/xml/features
Step 3 : features:install spring-mvc-smx

On that application Steps 2 and Step3, what it is doing and where it is pointing to ? Can you explain it little more ?

Comment: @Muthu I didn't write that tutorial, sorry.